# Passing in type of elements in collection to a function which initialises an ArrayList (Java)?

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like a function which takes in a parameter that then sets E in the ArrayList where E is the type of elements in this collection. So the simplest code showing what I want to do is as such, where E is what I don't know.

```
private void createArray(E dataType) {
    ArrayList<dataType> list = (ArrayList<dataType>) message.getArray();
}
```

Is this at all possible? I tried to find an answer by looking at the ArrayList class but I don't have much experience with Java.

Edit:
I am not sure if my question is clear enough... I don't need to pass the variable dataType. I need the variable dataType to be what goes into <> when I do the line where I initialise the ArrayList. I have found the following answer: [Pass class type as parameter to use in ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42069745/pass-class-type-as-parameter-to-use-in-arraylist) but it doesn't really work for me. I need to use the elements in the arraylist and call a method which only applies to that class...

```
    private <T> void createModel(String SQLcomm, Class<T> dataType, DefaultTableModel table) {
    Parcel parc = SQLtask(SQLcomm, "array");
    ArrayList<T> list = (ArrayList<T>) parc.getData();

    for (T t: list) {
        Vector<Object> newRow = t.getinfo();    //can't do t.getinfo()?
        table.addRow(newRow);
    }
```

Comment: what is "message" and what does "getArray" return ?

Comment: Can you post full self-contained example of a program that illustrates what you are trying to do? "I need the variable dataType to be what goes into <> when I do the line where I initialise the ArrayList" - You are not initializing an ArrayList? Is the "Vector newRow" or "t.getInfo()" related to the problem somehow?

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to access a `getinfo` method of the generic type parameter T? That will not work because T can be anything at all, for example String or Integer, any class that does not have your `getinfo` method. Where have you defined getinfo?

Answer (score 0):

An array isn't an ArrayList. But you can use something that method:

**If you have an array you can use:**

```
Arrays.asList(array);
```

**Otherwise**:

```
List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(element);
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's "possible" - you can write:

```
private <E> void createArray(E dataType) {
    ArrayList<E> list = (ArrayList<E>) message.getArray();
}
```

Comment: If `message.getArray` returns an array (how the method name says) it's not possible to cast to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to pass the data type as a class parameter, this is called genericity in java (for more info on genericity, here is a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) to the official java doc)
Example :

```
// E your data type
public class A<E> {
    //Maybe you get data from database (ResultSet)
    public void createArray(ResultSet message, String index) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<E> list = (ArrayList<E>) message.getArray(index);
        //the rest of the code...
    }
}
```

For more info on handling arrays [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html) is the official doc.